# Adjoint operator of multiplication operator on $\mathbb{R}[x]$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $\mathbb{R}[x]$ as a vector space of all polynomials with inner product $(f,g)=\int \limits_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx.$ Define an operator $\mathbf{A}$, whose value $\mathbf{A}(f)$ on arbitrary polynomial $f$ is defined by formula $\mathbf{A}(f)(x)=\int \limits_{a}^{b}P(x,y)f(y)dy$, where $P(x,y)$ is some fixed polynomial of two variables. Prove that adjoint operator $\mathbf{A}^{*}$ is given by formula $\mathbf{A}^{*}(f)(x)=\int \limits_{a}^{b}P(y,x)f(y)dy$.

**My approach:** We know that $(\mathbf{A}^{*}(f)(x),g(x))=(f(x),\mathbf{A}g(x))=\int \limits_{a}^{b}f(x)\mathbf{A}(g)(x)dx=\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(x)\int\limits_{a}^{b}P(x,y)g(y)dydx$

And I guess that I need somehow to change the order of integration to get smth like $(-,g(x))$ in order to compare it with $(\mathbf{A}^{*}(f)(x),g(x))$.

Would be very grateful for detailed answer!

This problem is from linear algebra and I guess that it should not be so difficult!

Answer (score 2):

$\langle g, Af \rangle = \int_{x=a}^b g(x) \int_{y=a}^b P(x,y)f(y)dy dx = \int_{y=a}^b  ( \int_{x=a}^b P(x,y)g(x)dx ) f(y)dy = \int_{y=a}^b  (A^*g)(y) f(y)dy = \langle A^*g,f \rangle$.

From which we get $(A^*g)(y) = \int_{x=a}^b P(x,y)g(x)dx$.

Comment: Hmmm... i did not think in this way. So you have found the operator $\mathbf{A}^*$ which satisfies this identity and since such operator is unique, so we are done right?

Comment: Yes. The map $f \mapsto \langle g, Af \rangle$ is linear hence by Riesz there is some $y_g$ such that $f \mapsto \langle g, Af \rangle = \langle y_g, f \rangle$. We define $A^* g = y_g$.

Comment: Wow .. unfortunately i am not familiar with Riesz theorem :( it was not covered in my linear algebra lectures. Are you using it somehow in the proof?

Comment: Not in the proof, it just states that a continuous linear functional in a Hilbert space can be represented as an inner product with some element of the Hilbert space. So in the above, the linear operator is $f \mapsto \langle g, Af \rangle$ and the corresponding element is $A^* g$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P(x,y)$ be a polynomial on $x$ and $y$. Then we can write $P$ as
$$P(x,y) = \sum_{i=0}^n p_ix^{c_i}y^{d_i} $$
for some $c_i$ and $d_i$, $i=1,...n$. And notice that
$$\mathbf{A}f(x) = \int \limits_{a}^{b}f(y) \sum_{i=0}^n p_i x^{c_i}y^{d_i}dy = \sum_{i=0}^n   p_i\int \limits_{a}^{b} f(y)x^{c_i}y^{d_i}dy$$
Then:
$$\langle\mathbf{A}^{*}(f)(x),g(x)\rangle=\langle f(x),\mathbf{A}g(x)\rangle=\int \limits_{a}^{b}f(x)\mathbf{A}(g)(x)dx=\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(x)\int\limits_{a}^{b}P(x,y)g(y)dydx=$$
$$\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(x)\int\limits_{a}^{b}\sum_{i=0}^n p_ix^{c_i}y^{d_i}g(y)dydx = \sum_{i=0}^n p_i\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(x)x^{c_i}\int\limits_{a}^{b}g(y)y^{d_i}dydx =$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^n p_i\int\limits_{a}^{b}\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(x)x^{c_i}g(y)y^{d_i}dydx=$$
now we can use Fubini's theorem to change the order of the integrations
$$=\sum_{i=0}^n p_i\int\limits_{a}^{b}\int\limits_{a}^{b} f(x)x^{c_i}g(y)y^{d_i}dxdy =
\sum_{i=0}^n p_i\int\limits_{a}^{b}g(y)y^{d_i}\int\limits_{a}^{b} f(x)x^{c_i}dxdy =$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^n p_i\int\limits_{a}^{b}g(y)\int\limits_{a}^{b} f(x)x^{c_i}y^{d_i}dxdy =\int\limits_{a}^{b} \left(\int\limits_{a}^{b}\sum_{i=0}^n p_i x^{c_i}y^{d_i} f(x)dx \right) g(y)dy =$$
$$ \langle\int\limits_{a}^{b}\sum_{i=0}^n p_i x^{c_i}y^{d_i} f(x)dx , g(x)\rangle$$
And now the left operand is written as a funcion of $y$. So relabeling the variables we have 
$$ \langle\mathbf{A}^{*}(f)(x),g(x)\rangle = \langle\int\limits_{a}^{b}\sum_{i=0}^n p_i y^{c_i}x^{d_i} f(y)dy , g(x)\rangle = \langle\int\limits_{a}^{b}P(y,x) f(y)dy , g(x)\rangle  $$